# AccessibilityTraversalBefore doesn't work with talkback

Tags: android-layout, talkback

I have a recycler view with a list of items. This is how it looks:

[image]

I need to add Talkback support. The problem is with the order of focusing inside recycler item view.

This should the correct order:

```
 1. Name of first member (A)
 2. Amount under first member's name (2469...)
 3. Name of second member (B)
 4. Amount under second member's name (2469...)
```

The problem is that default focus order is different:

```
    1) Name of the first member 
    2) Name of the second member 
    3) Amount under the first member
    4) Amount under the second member
```

The solution should be pretty easy. There is a parameter android:accessibilityTraversalBefore="@+id/someID" which change the order of focus. I use this parameter in other views in my app without a problem - it works nice. However when I use it here it doesn't have any effect at all - the views are still focused in the default order. 
Let's take a look at recycler item layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/vGuideline"
        style="@style/Layout.Guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/vFirstAvatar"
        style="@style/Image.AvatarMember"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/avatar_multiple" />

    <!-- Ellipsized because it can overlay the second member. -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/vFirstName"
        style="@style/TextView.NameEllipsized"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:accessibilityTraversalBefore="@+id/vFirstAmount"
        android:textAppearance="@style/ListPrimaryTiny"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/vFirstAvatar"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/vGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Suzan" />

    <!-- Ellipsized because it can overlay the second member. -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/vFirstAmount"
        style="@style/TextView.NameEllipsized"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:accessibilityTraversalBefore="@+id/vSecondName"
        android:textAppearance="@style/ListSecondary"
        android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/vFirstName"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/vGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vFirstName"
        tools:text="$22" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/vSecondAvatar"
        style="@style/Image.Avatar"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/avatar_multiple" />

    <!-- Ellipsized because it can overlay first member. -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/vSecondName"
        style="@style/TextView.NameEllipsized"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
        android:accessibilityTraversalBefore="@+id/vSecondAmount"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:textAppearance="@style/ListPrimaryTiny"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/vGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/vSecondAvatar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Dave" />

    <!-- Ellipsized because it can overlay the first member. -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/vSecondAmount"
        style="@style/TextView.NameEllipsized"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:textAppearance="@style/ListSecondary"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/vSecondName"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/vGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vSecondName"
        tools:text="$8" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Do you have any idea what is the reason why Talkback completely ignores 
AccessibilityTraversalBefore attribute?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [OrderedTraversalController](https://github.com/google/talkback/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/utils/traversal/OrderedTraversalController.java) in the "TalkBack" project, you can see that TalkBack does in fact respect this property.  I appologize, but I don't have time to set up a test for this and confirm, but my guess would be that setting this up in XML isn't going to work. It is likely that the recycler view is overriding the XML property at run time.

Try doing it in code after all the views have rendered.  Probably a few race conditions involved as well! I don't actually know what callback you would have to use to get this to happen reliably. I may investigate more later.